# webpack compilation error in the cypress test runner unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress

I have this Error: Webpack Compilation Error, after trying to import a component into my cypress test spec

am on React version 17.0.0 and React-dom v17.0.0

What might be causing this?

[here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAvO7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can see your webpack logs by running cypress when [documenting][1] in debug mode
[1]: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging#Print-DEBUG-logs

Mac/Linux

```
DEBUG=cypress:* cypress run
```

Windows

```
set DEBUG=cypress:*
cypress run
```

Everything you do in Cypress is logged in,
one of which is `cypress:webpack`, which can give you the full message.

And Also please try, adding an empty .babelrc file to the cypress roo directory allowed me to work around this issue.
`cypress/.babelrc`

```
{}
```